# Issue with dataTables bStateSave and using iDisplayLength

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to have dataTables remember the users last selection from pagination 
with `bStateSave: true`, as well as showing the user a default display length of 50 results using`iDisplayLength`

This is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide more details in your question (specifically, how you initialize your table), because the symptoms you describe could be caused by a number of issues.

Answer (score 2):

Delete all cookies beginning with `SpryMedia` on the relevant host, then try again.

Comment: I actually found the solution, by adding this: `"iCookieDuration": 60*60*24,//1day`